# How to write a method that returns number (int) of days from provided day to the todays date?

Tags: java

Please help me to write a method that returns number (int) of days from a provided day to the todays date.

So let's say, I am providing into a method an int `110515` (for May 15, 2011). It should return `9` (inclusive or exclusive is not important to me).

Comment: What representation is 110515, how is it encoded? Where did you get that number?

Comment: @Grega Kešpret: YYMMDD. It is an integer. I would pass it manually.

Comment: Oh sorry :) I was expecting "Excel" int encoded Date or something similar. We always miss too obvious things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should dates in the future include the current day? Meaning if today is May 24th 2011, should 110529 result in 4 or 5?

```
public static long numberOfDays(final long date) throws ParseException {
    final Calendar compare = Calendar.getInstance();
    compare.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd").parse(String.valueOf(date)));
    final int dstOffset = compare.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
    final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long compareTimeInMillis = compare.getTimeInMillis();
    long difference = 0;
    if (currentTimeMillis >= compareTimeInMillis) {
        difference = currentTimeMillis - compareTimeInMillis - dstOffset;
    } else {
        difference = compareTimeInMillis - currentTimeMillis + dstOffset;
    }
    return difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like a method. Can you modify it as a method?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Joda, this is super simple:

```
Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
int days = d.getDays();
```

Of course you could combine these.

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
```

Joda objects can go back and forth between the JDK's date class pretty easily.

For the first part, make a DateFormatter then parse the string based on it, like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(strInputDateTime);
```

(After turning the int into a string of course.)

Comment: What is Joda? Is it a new library? Do I need to import it? When I paste your code, DateTime is not recognized.

Comment: It's a time/date library that is about 100x better than the JDK date stuff (which is braindead). If you are using Maven, just add them as a dependency, otherwise, just download. Everyone uses it. Tiny lib, very clean code (compared to comparable machinations on the JDK).

Comment: @Rob, if I read your code correctly, I need to pass todays date manually. I want something that automatically picks up today's date.

Comment: @Prostak `DateTime()` creates an instance of a `DateTime` set to today's date/time.

Comment: @Rob, I've checked and unfortunately I can't download other libraries. Company has a policy restrictions on it. Would you be able to do it without Joda?

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems like a homework question I will help you out.  You will want to use `Calendar.getTimeInMillis`.  Then you will want to create a constant that is `NUMBER_OF_MILLIS_IN_DAY` .  From there you subtract the `initialDate` from the `currentDate` (both time in millis) and divide by the constant.